# Snowflake Data Load Wizard - File Format - how to handle null string in File Format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake Data Load Wizard to upload csv file to Snowflake table.  The Snowflake table structure identifies a few columns as 'NOT NULL' (non-nullable).   Problem is, the wizard is treating empty strings as null and  the Data Load Wizard issues the following error:

> Unable to copy files into table. NULL result in a non-nullable column
> File '@<...../load_data.csv', line 2, character 1 Row, 1 Column
> "<TABLE_NAME>" ["PRIMARY_CONTACT_ROLE":19)]

I'm sharing my File Format parameters from the wizard:

[image]

I then updated the DDL of the table by removing the "NOT NULL" declaration of the PRIMARY_CONTACT_ROLE column,  then re-create the table and this time the data load of 20K records is successful.

How do we fix the file format wizard to make SNOWFLAKE not consider empty strings as NULLS?

Answer (score 0):

The option you have to set `EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE`. Unfortunately, modifying this option is not possible in the wizard. You have to create your file format or alter your existing file format in a worksheet manually as follows:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT my_csv_format
TYPE = CSV
FIELD_DELIMITER = ','
SKIP_HEADER = 1
EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE;
```

This will cause empty strings to be not treated as NULL values but as empty strings.

The relevant documentation can be found at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-csv.

Let me know if you you need a full example of how to upload a CSV file with the SnowSQL CLI.

Just to add, there are additional ways you can load your CSV into snowflake without having to specify a file format.

You can use pre-built third-party modeling tools to  upload your raw file, adjust the default column types to your preference and push your modeled data back into snowflake.

My team and I are working on such a tool - Datameer, feel free to check it out here
https://www.datameer.com/upload-csv-to-snowflake/